# Copy text from Powershell without trailing whitespace

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I'm using Powershell (5.1.18362) in the new Windows Terminal preview (0.5.2681.0). If I try to copy multi-line text it treats the full width of the terminal as whitespace and copies it all (with no line breaks!) despite the application output having no trailing whitespace (for instance, when copying from a ruby IRB session).

Are there options to copy text without endless amounts of whitespace after every line? And with newlines properly captured?

Comment: Doesn't occur for me. Can you see if you're on the latest Windows Terminal version and if it still keeps happening, state how you reproduced it.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I believe I'm on the most updated version from the Windows Store. It's as simple as `ctrl+t` to open a tab, `dir` to print my home directory, highlight a block with my mouse and right click once to copy. Pasting this into an editor like sublime-text gives me one long line with 3000 characters. See https://i.imgur.com/WjfmqD5.png . I will note that it was DEFINITELY slightly inconsistent; one time it copied as expected (really threw me off!) but only once; every other test has just one line. Potentially affected by putting terminal in full-screen and back?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and finally found out the answer, if you copy the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it will copy it as one line, but if you copy it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it will copy the formatted text

Comment: In my experience, if you attempt to copy with ctrl-C that sends a ^C to the terminal, likely interrupting whatever process was running there.